# Recover data after partition format f2fs

Tags: data-recovery

I've accidentally format partition that was containing postgresql data. I realized quickly what I have done and haven't make anything more with this drive, so the data are untouched (I hope). The partition was f2fs type. 
I have made image of entire drive and try to recover using testdrive and photorec (ver 7.1-WIP) but without  any success. 
Can someone tell me how to deal this problem?